# FFMPEG decode from RTP dump file into mp3 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to save RTP stream into mp3 file. I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist file -f rtp -i microphone.rtpdump -f mp3 microphone.mp3
```

I get this result:

```
user@pc:~/$ ffmpeg-amrnb -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist file -f rtp -i microphone.rtpdump -f mp3 microphone.mp3
ffmpeg version N-100958-g4f3d8cb554 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 64.100 / 56. 64.100
  libavcodec     58.120.100 / 58.120.100
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7.102.100 /  7.102.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'rtp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'microphone.rtpdump'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp3'.
Reading option 'microphone.mp3' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url microphone.rtpdump.
Applying option f (force format) with argument rtp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: microphone.rtpdump.
[rtp @ 0x556947200580] Unable to receive RTP payload type 97 without an SDP file describing it
microphone.rtpdump: Invalid data found when processing input
```

It looks like that microphone.rtpdump file format is correct as ffmpeg can find RTP payload type 97. The problem is that I don't understand how to use SDP file in this situation.

I have an SDP file for this payload type which I use, when I send data over network. It looks like this:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.65.101
m=audio 1234 RTP/AVP 97
b=AS:12
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000/1
a=fmtp:97 octet-align=1
```

And now I want to decode RTP stream from file, not by receiving it from network.

How to adapt my SDP file to read RTP stream from file?

**UPDATE:** My rtpdump file is not a real rtpdump file format. It is just payloads from UDP packets written into file without any additional headers.

Comment: Did you ever find solution